# C# ExcelDataReader trim header columns

Tags: c#, exceldatareader

I'm reading a file by column names but in some files header columns contains trailing spaces.
I am aware of the ReadHeaderRow callback but how do I set the rowReader values?

```
var conf = new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
{
    ConfigureDataTable = a => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration
    {
        UseHeaderRow = true,
        ReadHeaderRow = (rowReader) => {
            for (int j = 0; j < rowReader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                rowReader[i] = rowReader.GetString(i).Trim(); // <- how to set the 'i' reader element?
            }    
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: It's not supported. The `ReadHeaderRow` callback is primarily meant to skip rows dynamically before the header and not actually reading/transforming the headers. A case of bad naming I guess. The next version of ExcelDataReader will introduce a new callback to transform cell values on the fly, but I suspect it won't work for headers. Best bet is to manipulate the column names in the dataset after reading.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure you will be able to manipulate the header record since it will define the "column" names of the dataset, and will not be part of the dataset itself.